# Rounded corners mess up on a collapsible div in IE7

Tags: jquery, jquery-corner

I have a div that is display: none on page load. I also have a button that toggles the display of the div (none to block). The first time after pageload that I click the button and show the div it has the assigned rounded corners (pic. 1 and 2). Then I click again to hide the div and click to show it. After that the rounded corners mess up (pic 2 and 3), the div expands some additional pixels (in height) and the rounded corners are not rounded anymore and with strange 'scanline' like lines in it.

The code:

```
<div id="filter-advanced">
<label for="filter-veld-value">
    <div class="filter-block and-block2">EN <span>
        <select name="filter-veld" id="filter-veld-name">
        <option value="">Kies een zoekveld...</option>
        <option value="domeinnaam_registrant">Domeinnaam registrant</option>
        <option value="domeinnaam_houder">Domeinnaam houder</option>
        <option value="provider_opmerkingen">Provider opmerkingen</option>
        <option value="ftp_opmerkingen">FTP opmerkingen</option>
        <option value="mysql_opmerkingen">MySQL opmerkingen</option>
        <option value="accc_cms_opmerkingen">CMS opmerkingen</option>
        <option value="stats_opmerkingen">Statistieken opmerkingen</option>
        <option value="opmerkingen">Overige opmerkingen</option>
    </select>                       
        bevat tekst</span>
    </div>
    <div class="filter-block">
        <input type="text" id="filter-veld-value" name="filter-veld-value" class="text" value="" />
    </div>
    <br class="clearboth" />
</label>
<label for="filter-regdatum-from-value">
    <div class="filter-block and-block3">EN <span>registratiedatum tussen</span></div>
    <div class="filter-block" id="regdatum">
        <input type="text" id="filter-regdatum-from-value" name="filter-regdatum-from-value" class="text-date" value="X1" />&nbsp;en&nbsp;&nbsp;<input type="text" id="filter-regdatum-to-value" name="filter-regdatum-to-value" class="text-date" value="X2" />
    </div>
    <br class="clearboth" />
</label>
<label for="filter-vvdatum-from-value">
    <div class="filter-block and-block3">EN <span>vervaldatum tussen</span></div>
    <div class="filter-block" id="vvdatum">
        <input type="text" id="filter-vvdatum-from-value" name="filter-vvdatum-from-value" class="text-date" value="X3" />&nbsp;en&nbsp;&nbsp;<input type="text" id="filter-vvdatum-to-value" name="filter-vvdatum-to-value" class="text-date" value="X4" />
    </div>
    <br class="clearboth" />
</label>
```

And the jQuery

```
    $("p#advanced-tab A").click(function(){
    if ($(this).hasClass('inactive'))
    {
        $(this).removeClass("inactive");
        $(this).addClass("active");
        $(this).text("Minder opties [-]");
        $("#filter-advanced").css("display", "block");
        $(this).corner("10px tr tl");
    }
    else
    {
        $(this).removeClass("active");
        $(this).addClass("inactive");
        $(this).text("Meer opties [+]");            
        $("#filter-advanced").css("display", "none");
    }
});
$("#filter-advanced").corner("10px tr bl br");
```

[alt text http://www.admixconnect.nl/images/TMPcorners/beeld1.jpg](http://www.admixconnect.nl/images/TMPcorners/beeld1.jpg)

[alt text http://www.admixconnect.nl/images/TMPcorners/beeld2.jpg](http://www.admixconnect.nl/images/TMPcorners/beeld2.jpg)

[alt text http://www.admixconnect.nl/images/TMPcorners/beeld3.jpg](http://www.admixconnect.nl/images/TMPcorners/beeld3.jpg)

[alt text http://www.admixconnect.nl/images/TMPcorners/beeld4.jpg](http://www.admixconnect.nl/images/TMPcorners/beeld4.jpg)

Comment: What Joey said, pictures don't help much on a coding site and I guarantee you're not doing something that hasn't been done before.

Answer (score 1):

Are you sliding the div with the rounded corners? Try sliding the inner div instead?

Comment: Thanx, good idea to try. Did that but didn't change the result.